# Can a non Nokia phone use app with Nokia Imaging SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am curious as to whether non Nokia Windows Phone 8 can run an app that uses the Nokia Imaging SDK, or if only Windows Phone 8 Nokia devices can run such apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all windows phones can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Tim said every Windows Phone can run Nokia Imaging SDK.

And also you can use Nokia Imaging SDK (since SDK 1.1) on your Windows 8 projects too.